# OBJECT_ID fails to find primary key

Tags: sql-server

I have a primary key called "PK_ABC.Sample" and I'm trying to find if it exists. For some reason I keep getting null when I call OBJECT_ID. For a quick test I changed the SQL to the following.

```
SELECT OBJECT_ID('PK_ABC.Sample') as 'Object Id'
```

I get a null result, which I understand means one of two things: it doesn't exist or I don't have permissions to see it.

Checking the sys.objects table I see that I have an entry called "PK_ABC.Sample" which has an object_id of 123 and type "PK".

Running the opposite operation `OBJECT_NAME(123)` results in the correct name "PK_ABC.Sample".

Why do I not get the value 123 when I run OBJECT_ID?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to enclose the name in brackets due to the period in the object name:

```
SELECT OBJECT_ID('[PK_ABC.Sample]');
```

I suggest you name objects following the rules for regular identifers (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx) to avoid this issue and make maintenance easier.

**EDIT:**

You added that ABC is the schema name, so you need to schema-qualify the name if is not in your default schema:

```
SELECT OBJECT_ID(N'ABC.[PK_ABC.Sample]');
```

I suspect someone accidentally (re)named the constraint as "PK_" followed by the schema-qualified table name.  This is redundant because table and column-level constraints are implicitly in the same schema as the parent table.  The intended name is likely "PK_Sample", which conforms to the identifier naming I mentioned earlier.

The redundant schema name and period can be removed with a rename:

```
EXEC sp_rename N'ABC.[PK_ABC.Sample]', N'PK_Sample';
```

You can then get the object id without the brackets and confusion:

```
SELECT OBJECT_ID(N'ABC.PK_Sample');
```

Comment: Thanks. Already tried this, unfortunately it didn't help. Just forgot to include the brackets when I wrote the question here. ABC is my schema and Sample is the table name. Not sure what is wrong with my identifier, please clarify. Thx.

Comment: That worked, was missing the Schema before the name. The identifier was created by EntityFramework, I didn't define it. I think they like to include the schema to prevent a conflict if you have the same table name in 2 different Schemas.

Comment: Schema-qualifying the table name certainly makes sense but I'm not sure why EF embedded the schema name in the the constraint name.  Aside from the stand-alone reference for OBJECT_ID, constraint names are specified in the context of the parent table name so the schema name of the parent table is implicit.